# Binding<Int> when expected argument type 'Int' SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm  learning about UserDefaults storage and I'm getting a warning when I try to apply the code from another Class: `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type 'Int'`

This is my code:

```
@ObservedObject var eatTracker = TimeToEatTrackerViewModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 30) {
        Button(action: {
            self.$eatTracker.currentMeal += 1
            print(self.$eatTracker.currentMeal)
        }){
            Text("Who's next?")
        }

    }
}
```

and the other class which has the ViewModel:

```
class TimeToEatTrackerViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var currentMeal: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "CurrentMeal") {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.currentMeal, forKey: "CurrentMeal")
    }
}
}
```

Why am I getting that error if both are Int?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
self.eatTracker.currentMeal += 1
print(String(self.eatTracker.currentMeal))
```